# jQuery DataTables plugin - secondary sorting (multiple column)

Tags: jquery, sorting, jquery-plugins, datatables

I can't find a solution for this in DataTables plugin. What I want is to have secondary sorting. What I mean by that is - for example, I have a table with product name and price, something like this:

```
    NAME               PRICE
    A product          22.00 $
    C product          50.00 $
    B product          50.00 $
    D product          50.00 $
    E product          26.00 $
    F product          12.00 $
```

When the user clicks on PRICE this happens:

```
    NAME               PRICE
    F product          12.00 $
    A product          22.00 $
    E product          26.00 $
    C product          50.00 $
    B product          50.00 $
    D product          50.00 $
```

But I need this to happen:

```
    NAME               PRICE
    F product          12.00 $
    A product          22.00 $
    E product          26.00 $
    B product          50.00 $
    C product          50.00 $
    D product          50.00 $

    (note the last three products - they are sorted a-z)
```

Or basically, I need what's described [here](http://datatables.net/forums/comments.php?DiscussionID=1835&page=1).

Thanks in advance if you have any ideas!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, forgot to answer here. I've found a solution - use the aaSort function but you need to patch it in the script. Change line 4085 to:

```
aaSort = oSettings.aaSorting.concat( oSettings.aaSortingFixed );
```

Comment: Hi, Could you post your answer. I need same thing.

Comment: It was more than two years ago, but I think the answer is right there: use the aaSort function, but patch your script beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 oTable.fnSort( [ [0,'asc'], [1,'asc'] ] );
```

Comment: It will sort immediately with columns 0 and 1.